# A media type with MFAudioFormat_Float subtype returns TRUE when calling IsCompressedFormat(), is this possible?

Tags: windows, ms-media-foundation, audio-player

While examining the supported input media types returned by the Streaming Audio Renderer sink [(SAR)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369729(v=vs.85).aspx) I am receiving a media type having as subtype `MFAudioFormat_Float`, that also returns `TRUE` when the `ISCompressedFormat()` function is called for the type.

In my mind `MFAudioFormat_Float` is the floating-point flavor of `MFAudioFormat_PCM` (in other words, no compression is being used, but samples have 32-bit accuracy). **In this case, how can I find what kind of compression is being used?**

Incidentally, this media type returns `MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND` when I attempt to query the `MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS` attribute, which also makes no sense to me.

Comment: To answer this question, you should rather enumerate all media type attributes and values and having all that in front of you identify why the media type could be treated as compressed. It might so happen it has `MF_MT_COMPRESSED` value and subtype just has no effect. Media Foundation media type is mostly a collection of attributes with a dedicated attribute that tells whether it is compressed or not. The values don't have to fit one another nicely, there is no strict checking that.

Comment: @thanks Roman R. With all the information in front, I still can't figure out the media type - however, I'm only able to play back audio with the type that does not carry the MF:MT_COMPRESSED attribute, so I'm ignoring the other formats.  Thanks for the heads up!